# Google Apps stops sending email every few days

Tags: django, email, google-apps

Every few days, google apps starts rejecting my username and password with :

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 22sm439603yxe.15')
```

If I go to the google apps login page and try my password, it asks for a captcha. Filling it out correctly, now allows me to send email again for a few days until this happens again.

How can I stop this from happening? Has anyone else seen this when sending automated emails through google apps?

I'm sending registration emails from my website using these settings in django :

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'metaward@metaward.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*secret*'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: I really hope your password is not '*secret*' :-)

Comment: I find that the captcha request appears when the email password fails a few times. You could try changing the email id (incase someone ese is trying to guess your pass, or you have an app set with the wrong password), and following google's instructions at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14257 and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Unless you say what is the password you enter, it is hard to find why ;)

Comment: @Alterlife ok, I'll try changing accounts since metaward@metaward.com is easy to guess. @becomingGuru, you better not be the one trying to guess my password ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throttle your requests to an acceptable rate for Google Apps.

I am not sure if Google has an official statement/guidance about what is the acceptable request rate, though. If you can't find any such public statement/guidance, you should contact Google Apps support to see if you can get it through there.

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=245780a083285e00&hl=en . Not much faith they'll get back to me. Any other avenues you know of?

Comment: No, I am not aware of other venues to get support from Google. Well, you could always look for a-friend-of-a-friend-type connection to a Google employee. Or ping Matt Cutts on Twitter. :-)

Unfortunately, with Google Apps you get what you paid for. And for free/$50-a-year, you don't get that much of support.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum limit for sending emails for a given email account per day is 3000. But it is unlikely that you are sending as many emails every day. Even the error message isn't indicating that.

While, the resolution to the actual question can only be resolved by google, the way to circumvent this problem may be by setting up different email users, and choosing one at random.

Comment: Yeah, there is no way I hit 3000, maybe 30 at most.

Maybe I should just give up on sending through gmail and do it directly through SMTP...

Answer (score 0):

### Use OAuth2:

Explained at http://www.nodemailer.com/

> Gmail has came up with the concept of 'less secure' apps which is
>   basically anyone who uses plain password to login to Gmail, so you
>   might end up in a situation where one username can send (support for
>   'less secure' apps is enabled) but other is blocked (support for 'less
>   secure' apps is disabled).
>
> To prevent having login issues you should either use XOAUTH2  or use
>   another provider and preferably a dedicated one like Mailgun or
>   SendGrid